# How I pass data of all activites to final activity?

Tags: android

I have four activities named activity1, activity2, activity3, activity4 and finalactivity. I build CV Builder that take information of person in different activities.

Now I want to send data of activity1 to activity2, I used intent for this purpose, but now I do not understand how I send the data of both activities (1 and 2) to activity3, and so on. Finally I want to send data of all four activities to finalactivity, any help?

Comment: SharedPreferences is golable to store data

Comment: pls explain what you actually want to do by providing data?

Comment: I want to display data which I get in four activities in last activity. Like I get personal info in first activity, educational info in second activity, experiences in 3rd activity and projects detail in fourth activity now I want to show this info in final activity, all info in one activity.

Comment: you should use pojo if you don't want to store it for longer time

Comment: Is it possible that I make intent in first activity and push some data and start second activity, in second activity I get that intent and push some other data and start third activity and so on.

Comment: yes it is possible by serializing data but the got approach is here  to use pojo as explained by @mysticmagic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the data of Activity1 and Activity2 into one bundle and send it to Activity3 (because you already have the data of Activity1 in Activity2), and continue doing this till Activity 4. This is kinda obvious.
Is there any specific problem that is stopping you from doing this?

Alternatively, you can use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the data from each of the Activities and then retrieve them in Activity4.

Just remember to remove the data from sharedpreferences once you are done in Actiuvity4

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to use Application class.

Make a POJO class for CV data. And keep a single object in Application class. Update data in that class in all activity's Submit click. So you can use the updated CV data in last activity.

EXAMPLE:

```
public class CVData{
    //your String, int, getter, setter, etc.
}
```

Application class:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    //Object declaration
    public CVData cvData;

    public TestApplication () {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    //setter getter for object
}
```

Now in your Activity:

```
//after setContentView
TestApplication testAppObj = (TestApplication) getApplication();
myCVObj.setName("abc");
myCVObj.setEducation("engg");
testAppObj.setSomeObj(myCVObj);

//retrieve and update in other activities as:
someCVObj = testAppObj.getterMethodOfObj();
someCVObj.setGoal("learn");
testAppObj.setSomeObj(someCVObj);
```

So you will get the updated object in last activity using:

```
CVData updatedCVObj = testAppObj.getterMethodOfObj();
```

You must register your Application class in your manifest file just like you register your activities:

```
<application
        android:name="com.pkg.test.TestApplication " />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow different approaches :

**1.** Shared Preference

You can simply add all value in `SharedPreferences` and use it in Final activity

**2.** DataModel class

Create a bean class which holds all data. Set the value in that class object and use it in Final activity

Class :

```
public class  ResumeData {
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }
```

Take a static object and use it to set and get the value :

> public static ResumeData resumeData;

```
resumeData = new ResumeData();
// Set 
resumeData.setName("name");
// Get 
resumeData.getName()
```

**3.** Send aggregate data to final activity

You can get Activity1's data in Activity2. Simply send Activity1's data too with bundle to next activity.

Hope it will help you ツ